# Issue Java 6 daylight saving's time for Brazil

Tags: java, date

I´ve been facing strange issue with Brazil´s daylight saving's time in Java.

The daylight saving's time started at 10/20/2013 in Brazil so now we are 2 hours behind from Greenwich.

My problem is: I have dates stored on my database Oracle like this 10/20/2013 00:00:00 as you can see, We don´t store the hours,minutes and seconds even timezone.
When we load this date to JAVA(java.sql.Date to java.util.Date) , it adds one hour like this: 10/20/2013 01:00:00, but should be 10/20/2013 00:00:00

Has anyone faced this issue? I checked my tzupdater and it´s updated.

My version of JAVA is: java6_u45

Comment: I don't think this is wrong, there is no TimeZone info with that timestamp. Java will load using the current BRST timezone (It will get from the current OS config) the 10/20/2013 00:00:00 checking if is DST and add the one hour. Now to avoid that you can load the date and convert to GMT-3 that doesn't have DST information. I suppose it works. Oh, check if that isn't 10/20/2013 01:00:00 with offset of -2. If it is, it represent the same time as 10/20/2013 00:00:00 with offset -3. It's not wrong, but probably break your queries.

Comment: Hi Andre that is my problem, this issue is breaking my queries on database. I will perform your idea.

Comment: I had this problem also, we solved by setting all the timestamps to 12PM (Meio dia) and working only with it. You can also ask for Hibernate to deal only with date, not timestamps. Edit all your POJOs with `TemporalType.DATE` and update the database columns according.

Comment: Hi André I´m not using JPA. I am using JDBC pure

Comment: Hi Andre I tried that:

Date d = fmt.parse("20/10/2013 00:00:00");
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
boolean inDs = tz.inDaylightTime(d);
log.info("Date is in DST "+inDs+" Format  "+fmt.format(d));

if (inDs){
TimeZone tz1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-3");
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(tz1);
cal.clear();
cal.setTime(d);
log.info("Date is in DST  after GMT-3 "+inDs+" Format  "+fmt.format(cal.getTime()));
}
But the issue still happens. I think JAVA understands which 20/10/2013 00:00:00 does not exist because we won one hour more...

Comment: The `DateFormat` you use parses the date and uses the system `TimeZone`. Set the `TimeZone` of the `DateFormat` instance using `fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-3"));` before parsing the new date. It will output false to `isDST()`

Answer (score 3):

`java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` does not carry timezone information. They just represent an instant in the time, in the approach of "xy amounts of milliseconds passed from the epoch".

`java.sql.Date`: "A 
 * milliseconds value represents the number of milliseconds that 
 * have passed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT."

`java.util.Date`: "the `Date` class is intended to reflect 
 * coordinated universal time (UTC)"

What is the datatype you store the datetime on the sql side?

Comment: Hi gyabraham, the datatype of field is DATE on Oracle.

Comment: @RaphaelMilani You should update your question with this kind of critical information (data type used in database).

Answer (score 1):

> I have dates stored on my database Oracle like this 10/20/2013 00:00:00 as you can see, We don´t store the hours,minutes and seconds even timezone.

…

> the datatype of field is DATE on Oracle

You are incorrect in two regards:

- You are *not* storing dates like `10/20/2013 00:00:00`. You are using Oracle's [DATE data type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847) which is a proprietary binary format that contains components for century, year, month, day, hour, minute, and second, but no time zone.
- You *are* indeed storing time components. The DATE type in Oracle automatically plugs in a value of 00:00:00 A.M. (midnight) if you provide no other time value.

If you are going to use the DATE type in Oracle, you should always convert values to [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)/GMT before passing to Oracle. Likewise, when pulling DATE values out of Oracle, consciously convert the value to a desired time zone knowing that Oracle is handing you a UTC value.

If you try to store a zoned date-time in an Oracle DATE type, you are going to have all kinds of problems. One of those problems is that in some time zones, *there is no midnight* on some days such as [Daylight Savings Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) (DST). Guess what… **Brazil is one of those time zones without a midnight**. DST causes the clock to [jump one hour forward](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=45) at the stroke of midnight, to 01:00. This year, that happened on October 19-20, 2013.

As [the correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20267950/642706) by gyabraham said, [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) and [java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) have no time zone, so you must be using [java.util.Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) as well. Study your code.

One problem then is that you are trying to store date values in a date-time data type. And then complaining of problems with the time component. That's like storing integers in a real/decimal data type and then complaining that your numbers have fractions.

If you want to store dates, then use a date type. Unfortunately, it seems Oracle does not offer such a type (but don't trust me on this, I'm a [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/) guy and don't know Oracle). But there is very simple workaround. This workaround assumes you truly want dates only, no time, which means no handling of time zones and the fact that the same date does not happen around the world simultaneously. The workaround is using a textual type such as VARCHAR to store YYYY-MM-DD values. For example, 2013-10-20. I suggest including the hyphens for readability, unless you have humongous amounts of data thereby justifying their removal. By ordering year-month-day, the values compare and sort alphabetically. You can search for date ranges by querying for greater-than/less-than.

But often when people think they want a date-only value, they are mistaken. That date only has meaning in some unspecified time zone, presumably your currently local time zone. But when someone in [Dubai](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=776) or [Paris](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=195) asks for a list of yesterday's invoices, do they mean *their* yesterday or *your* yesterday? Each began and ended at different times.

Best practice is to store your date-time values in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (no time zone offset). And also store the local date-time and time zone info if that matters to you for the sake of history. When retrieving those UTC date-times, convert explicitly to a desired time zone. Avoid depending on default time zone of the particular computer. Further tip, avoid using 3-letter time zone codes as they are not standardized and often have multiple meanings; use [time zone names](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html) instead.

Stop using java.util.Date/Calendar, as they are notoriously bad. Use the third party [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library. Invest some time reading their doc, and looking at examples here on StackOverflow.com. Pass your java.sql.Date values into and out of Joda-Time [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) instances. Later, in Java 8, consider moving to [JSR 310: Date and Time API](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) which is inspired by Joda-Time but entirely re-architected.

Lastly, Joda-Time has a specific solution to this problem of no-midnight: the method [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()) determines the appropriate first moment of the day. In [Brazil on October 20th](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=45), that would have been 01:00 not 00:00.

Lessons Learned:

- Be aware of your data types.
- Read the doc.
- Know that not every day in every time zone has a midnight. Never stuff zeros into a time component and assume that is valid and means midnight.
- Always think about time zones. Know what time zone (or UTC) is in play; never assume.
- Store globally, think locally. Store date-times in UTC. Try to do most business logic in UTC. Convert to time zoned date-times only when humans require it (in presentation or in business logic such as "today" invoices).
- Understand that a [java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) is a [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) (a subclass). Neither has time zone information.
- Use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Use the java.util.Date/[Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) classes only as required for exchanging data. Or, in Java 8, use the new [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) [java.time.*](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.